# Best way to create a navigation bar

Tags: html

i've seen three main ways of creating a nagivation bar and was wondering what way is best or more efficient. They all do pretty much the same thing.

## 1: Use the nav HTML tag.

Example of #1:

```
<nav>
<a href="#">Home</a> |
<a href="#">About</a> |
<a href="#">Blog</a> |
<a href="#">Sign in</a>
</nav>
```

## 2: Simply use an unordered list.

Example of #2

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a> |</li>
<li><a href="#">About</a> |</li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a> |</li>
<li><a href="#">Sign in</a> |</li>
</ul>
```

After this one, you would use css to *display* it inline or you could use a float.

## 3: Only use the  tag.

Example of #3:

```
  <a href="#">Home</a> |
  <a href="#">About</a> |
  <a href="#">Blog</a> |
  <a href="#">Sign in</a>
```

This way is essentially like using nav, but you'd have to insert some css like example#2 to make it float:left or display:inline.

I've seen those three ways of making a navigation bar, and I was wondering which way you guys recommend me creating a navigation bar.

I'd also like to hear your guys' thoughts on using float:left vs display:inline .

Thanks and have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the question here? This should be a knowledge base, not public poll site.

> They all do pretty much the same thing.

Exactly as you said, all three examples do the same thing:

- No.1 is the youngest approach, featuring the HTML5 nav element
- No.2 used to be a standard before that
- No.3 is also fine if you don't require additional styling to the navigation item's container elements.

All of them can be made to work exactly like the others with just a few CSS rules... so the answer to your question is: it's only about the **semantics**, there is no difference in **efficiency**.

---

```css
#m2 ul {padding: 0}
#m2 li {display: inline-block}
```

```html
<div id="m1">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a> |
    <a href="#">Home</a> |
    <a href="#">About</a> |
    <a href="#">Blog</a> |
    <a href="#">Sign in</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="m2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a> |</li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a> |</li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a> |</li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a> |</li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="m3">
  <a href="#">Menu 3</a> |
  <a href="#">Home</a> |
  <a href="#">About</a> |
  <a href="#">Blog</a> |
  <a href="#">Sign in</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using  tag your code will be *easier to read and maintain*.Remember that there are times that you write code that might be read by an other one .So if someone reads your html they should be able to understand what it doew the the minimum possible time.Also it will be easier for you to read and I believe that it would require less css rules than your 3rd approach.